# Is there an easy way to identify the subject in a relative clause?

Tags: verb-agreement

I am having a problem deciding whether to use "is" or "are" here, as I do not really know what the subject is... I feel that the sentence is OK as is but my Word grammar checker says "is" would be the correct verb (not a deal-breaker for me, but it certainly helps to cast doubt).

> ... a typical part of his oeuvre, in which death and transience are a central motif.

I am sure there must be an "easy" way to tell what the subject is, and therefore whether the verb will be singular or plural, but I guess I missed that lesson at school!

Comment: You have to identify your meaning, we can't. Either death and transience are central motifs, or death and transience is a central motif. If two themes, they are motifs. If one paired concept, it is central.

Comment: I should have mentioned that it is not my sentence, I am proofreading it. I suppose I would then have to ask the author to identify the subject here.

Comment: In your opinion, what are the candidate possibilities for the subject? I'm asking because I only see one credible candidate noun phrase that can act as a subject before the "are" in your sample sentence, but your question implies that there are more.

Comment: Such conceptualisations are woolly probably by design. One thinks of the ill-defined slash in << death / transience >> ([death] + [transience] {are ...} _or_ [death & transience] {is ...}; cf 'health and safety is our primary concern'; take your pick, reader) As Yosef says, both readings are available, but it's best to ask the author to clarify. You're looking for a grammatical rule to decide what is 'the right answer', but both are acceptable, with different thrusts.

Comment: If I'm editing, I'm now in charge! Sorta. So I'd take a big breath and say that *death and transience* are close enough to being a single theme and already match *central motif*. The singular verb even pleases the Grammar God.

Comment: As far as I can tell (and judging from others' comments), your question has nothing to do with the fact that the terms appear in a relative clause, so you may want to edit the title. The primary issue seems to be the fact that the subject is compound.

Answer (score 0):

If “death and transience” were a single concept in the same way as “ham and eggs”, “war and peace”, “eggs and bacon”, “horse and carriage” and many other unified concepts, it might be expected to show up in a Google ngram search.

It does not, so we might reasonably conclude that “death” and “transience” are intended as separate notions and that a safe usage would be “are” rather than “is”.

Comment: On the other hand, we're comparing very low numbers of examples. Both ['death and transcience is' and 'death and transience are'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=death+and+transcience+is%2Cdeath+and+transcience+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=) flatline in Google 4-gram searches. The author is the only one who can tell us how closely related the concepts are in ttheir personal estimation, so this is POB.